# Reading key values a JSON array which is a set in Python

Tags: python, json, variables, set

I have the following code

```
import requests
import json
import sys

credentials_User=sys.argv[1]
credentials_Password=sys.argv[2]
email=sys.argv[3]

def auth_api(login_User,login_Password,):

    gooddata_user=login_User
    gooddata_password=login_Password
    body = json.dumps({
    "postUserLogin":{
        "login": gooddata_user,
        "password": gooddata_password,
        "remember":1,
        "verify_level":0
    }
    })
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    url="https://reports.domain.com/gdc/account/login"

    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body
    )
    sst=response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
    return sst

def query_api(cookie,email):

    url="https://reports.domain.com/gdc/account/domains/domain/users?login="+email
    
    body={}

    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': cookie
    }

    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body
    )
    jsonContent=[]
    jsonContent.append({response.text})
    accountSettings=jsonContent[0]
    print(accountSettings)


cookie=auth_api(credentials_User,credentials_Password)
profilehash=query_api(cookie,email)
```

The code itself works and sends a request to the Gooddata API.

The query_api() function returns JSON similar to below

```
{
  "accountSettings": {
    "items": [
      {
        "accountSetting": {
          "login": "user@example.com",
          "email": "user@example.com",
          "firstName": "First Name",
          "lastName": "Last Name",
          "companyName": "Company Name",
          "position": "Data Analyst",
          "created": "2020-01-08 15:44:23",
          "updated": "2020-01-08 15:44:23",
          "timezone": null,
          "country": "United States",
          "phoneNumber": "(425) 555-1111",
          "old_password": "secret$123",
          "password": "secret$234",
          "verifyPassword": "secret$234",
          "authenticationModes": [
            "SSO"
          ],
          "ssoProvider": "sso-domain.com",
          "language": "en-US",
          "ipWhitelist": [
            "127.0.0.1"
          ],
          "links": {
            "projects": "/gdc/account/profile/{profile_id}/projects",
            "self": "/gdc/account/profile/{profile_id}",
            "domain": "/gdc/domains/default",
            "auditEvents": "/gdc/account/profile/{profile_id}/auditEvents"
          },
          "effectiveIpWhitelist": "[ 127.0.0.1 ]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "offset": 20,
      "count": 100,
      "next": "/gdc/uri?offset=100"
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is reading specific keys from this JSON Dict, I can use `accountSettings=jsonContent[0]` but that just returns the same JSON.

What I want to do is read the value of the `project` key within `links`

How would I do this with a dict?

Thanks

Comment: It's [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). To read login you should use `jsonContent["accountSettings"]["items"][0]["accountSetting"]["login"]`

Comment: To me, it's not really clear what you're doing. Neither what your input is, nor what your code does with it. Please provide a [mcve] which people can just run.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt reflecting back i do agree, I have updated the original question now. Thank you

Comment: I can't run that without credentials... Anyhow, is it the actual request or the processing of the result giving you issues? That is one important part for you to work out while extracting a [mcve]!

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt its the processing of the result which gives me issue, specifically a single value from one of the JSON keys. Thanks

Comment: `jsonContent.append({response.text})` does not actually parse the JSON. You should instead use `jsonContent = response.json`. After that, you work with the structured data the same way you would if it had come from anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, uyou have your value inside a list, (not a `set`. Foergt about `set`: sets are not used with JSON). Inside your list, you either your content as a single string, which then you'd have to parse with `json.loads`, or it is simply a well behaved nested data structure already extracted from JSON, but which is inside a single element list. This seems the most likely.

So, you should be able to do:

```
accountlink = jsonContent[0]["items"][0]["accountSetting"]["login"]
```

otherwise, if it is encoded as a a json string, you have to parse it first:

```
import json
accountlink = json.loads(jsonContent[0])["items"][0]["accountSetting"]["login"]
```

Now, given your question, I'd say your are on a begginer level as a programmer, or a casual user, just using Python to automatize something either way, I'd recommend you do try some exercising before proceeding: it will save you time (a lot of time). I am not trying to bully or mock anything here: this is the best advice I can offer you. Seek for tutorials that play around on the interactive mode, rather than trying entire programs at once that you'd just copy and paste.

Comment: thanks for helping! Yes I am not an experienced programmer, I am hoping to change that soon. I tried your first suggestion but received the following error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apiauth.py", line 62, in <module>
    profilehash=query_api(cookie,email)
  File "apiauth.py", line 57, in query_api
    accountlink = jsonContent[0]["items"][0]["accountSetting"]["login"]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable```.

Comment: The 2nd suggestion also gives me an error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apiauth.py", line 62, in <module>
    profilehash=query_api(cookie,email)
  File "apiauth.py", line 57, in query_api
    accountlink = json.loads(jsonContent[0])["items"][0]["accountSetting"]["login"]
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not set
```

Comment: Ok, sou you indeed ended up with a "set" - that should not happen with a straightforward json reading. convert the set to a "list" first. This should work, unless the "set" is one of the inner elements: 
`accountlink = list(jsonContent) [0]["items"][0]["accountSetting"]["login"]` from your posting, the set might be one of the inner elements, at which point it'd real;ly help if you knew what you are doing, but try this last shot: `accountlink = list(jsonContent [0]["items"])[0]["accountSetting"]["login"]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately didn't work but I'll do some practice to work out the different data types. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code fixed the issue

```
jsonContent=json.loads(response.text)
print(type(jsonContent))
test=jsonContent["accountSettings"]["items"][0]
test2=test["accountSetting"]["links"]["self"]
print(test)
print(test2)
```

I believe this works because for some reason I didn't notice I was using .append for my jsonContent. This resulted in the data type being something other than it should have been.

Thanks to everyone who tried helping me.